# Select box default selected value not showing in selectbox in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

[image]

I'm trying to do a select operation with default value set for my edit page. However, it's not showing in select box

```
<select name=moduleId [(ngModel)]="moduleName" >
          <option value="{{model.moduleId}}" selected>{{moduleName}}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let accss of access" value="{{accss.moduleId}}">{{accss.moduleName}}</option>     
</select>
```

showing like this default value is right below in options.

Comment: Should {{moduleName}} be {{model.moduleName}} ?  And are you sure [(ngModel)]="moduleName"  is proper syntax?

Comment: thanks for those comments, i made some changes in my model class and now its working fine @Zze ,@ Anthony McGrath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this `value="{{model.moduleId}}"` to `value="{{moduleName}}"`

```
<select name='moduleId' [(ngModel)]="moduleName">
        <option value="{{moduleName}}" selected>{{moduleName}}</option>            
        <option *ngFor="let accss of access" value="{{accss.moduleId}}">{{accss.moduleName}}</option>     
  </select>
```

and in component add object as

```
access = [{
    moduleId: 1,
    moduleName: 'abc'
}, {
    moduleId: 2,
    moduleName: 'def'
}];
moduleName = 'Select';
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be `value` in options change to `[value]` attribute binding

```
<select  name=moduleId [(ngModel)]="moduleName" >
    <option *ngFor="let accss of access" [value]="{{accss.moduleId}}">{{accss.moduleName}}</option>  // change to this   
</select>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
export class Component {  
    moduleName: any = <yourselecteddefaut>;   
  }
```